# Paypal SDK getting error when passing more than one purchaseUnits for OrderRequest in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, sdk

My code for paypal sdk is like below

```
func makePaypalPayment(amount:String,userEmail:String,eChitthiAmount:String) {
         Checkout.start(
            createOrder: { createOrderAction in
            // This order is for eChitthi
            let amountForeChitthi = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .usd, value: eChitthiAmount)
            let purchaseUnitForeChitthi = PurchaseUnit(amount: amountForeChitthi)
            
            // This order is for user
            let amount = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .usd, value: amount)
            let payeeDetail = PurchaseUnit.Payee(emailAddress:userEmail)
            let purchaseUnit = PurchaseUnit(amount: amount,payee: payeeDetail)
            let order : OrderRequest = OrderRequest(intent: .capture, purchaseUnits: [purchaseUnit,purchaseUnitForeChitthi])
            createOrderAction.create(order: order)
            
        }, onApprove: { approval in
            approval.actions.capture { (response, error) in
                print("Payment successfully")
            }
        }, onCancel: {
            print("Order is cancelled.")
        }, onError: { error in
            print("Order have some error.")
        }
    )
}
```

Here I want to make two transaction for one payment. Like user want to transfer $100 to his friend then 1% charge will be gone to application's owner.

So I my scenario If userA want to transfer $100 to userB then total amount $101 will be cut from userA's paypal account and $100 will goes to userB's account and $1 goes to application's owner account. For that I created two **PurchaseUnit** object and passed both into OrderRequest. Because of that getting **The operation couldn’t be completed. (OrderActionError error 202.)**

I am using SDK : PayPalCheckout (0.73.0)

Language : Swift

Help (I have implemented code from this document) - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/ios/programmatically-start-sdk/

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: "SwiftUI" is not a language -- it's a UI framework. This question doesn't seem to deal with SwiftUI at all and only Swift (which is a language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying multiple purchase_units in an orders creation request, each must have a unique `reference_id`, as they are independent payments and may succeed or fail individually. They will also result in independent PayPal transactions.

This is documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body

Comment: Thanks @Preston PHX. It is very helpful for me. Thanks a lot